# How to find roots of very complex equation on Python?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, equation, solver

How do I solve this (f(r)=0) on Python?:

```
def f(r):
     return -6*r**2*(pi - 1/cos(2.4e-6*sqrt(3)/r)) - 3*r**2*(2*cos(pi/6 - 1/cos(2.4e-6*sqrt(3)/r))*cos(1/cos(2.4e-6*sqrt(3)/r)) - pi/2 + 1/cos(2.4e-6*sqrt(3)/r)) - (-2.88e-5*sqrt(3) + 0.000207846096908265)*cos(pi/6 - 1/cos(2.4e-6*sqrt(3)/r)) + 5.19615242270663e-10
```

Comment: My answer should work for a generic function, but your specific equation may not have a suitable root because you are dividing by `r`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html). You just have to pass in an initial guess.

```
from scipy.optimize import root
initial_guess = 1
solution = root(fun=f, x0=initial_guess)

print(solution)
#    fjac: array([[-1.]])
#     fun: array([-4.73292067e-21])
# message: 'The solution converged.'
#    nfev: 50
#     qtf: array([7.59795519e-16])
#       r: array([-99.77979489])
#  status: 1
# success: True
#       x: array([1.46358719e-06])
```

As a check, we can plug the solution back into your function:

```
print(f(solution.x[0]))
#-4.732920669875286e-21
```

Which is essentially 0.